# How can I conditionally validate a validation created on a item within Oracle Application Express?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I added a not-null validation to one of my oracle-apex form items. I want that to be executed only when one of other items in my form is set to some specific value.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create validation with type `PL/SQL expression` and implement any validation logic there, like this:

```
(:P_NUMBER_ITEM = 1 and :P_STRING_ITEM is not null) or :P_NUMBER_ITEM <> 1
```

In this example validation requires NOT NULL value in `P_STRING_ITEM` only when `P_NUMBER_ITEM` Is equal `1`.